# Cambiar de vista Vue a través de botón

Tags: javascript, vue.js

estoy intentando cambiar de componente a través de darle click a un botón porque antés de cambiar de vista tengo que hacer una comprobación de datos y demás.

```
  methods: {
    sendToView(msg, view) {
      console.log(msg, view);
    },
  },
```

aqui tengo la funcion que hace el boton, donde view es la vista dónde estoy, y al validar ciertos datos, poder pasar a la siguiente, mi pregunta es como cambiar de componente desde el boton sin tener que usar vue router, ya que no encuentro nada al respecto.

Componente boton:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <button @click="sendToView(msg, view)">{{ msg }}</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import router from "../router"

export default {
  name: "button-lvl",
  props: {
    msg: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    view: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
  },
  methods: {
    sendToView(msg, view) {
      console.log(view);
      if(view === "hello-app"){
        router.push('/firstlevel');
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

router index.js

```
import { createWebHistory, createRouter } from "vue-router";
import Home from "@/components/views/HelloApp.vue";
import FirstLevel from "@/components/views/FirstLevel.vue";

const routes = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "HelloApp",
    component: Home,
  },
  {
    path: "/firstlevel",
    name: "FirstLevel",
    component: FirstLevel,
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(),
  routes,
});

export default router;
```

Comment: No se a que te referis con "cambiar de componente", supongo que queres cambiar de vista. Hasta donde yo se las vistas se enlazan con las rutas en el enrutador, y la documentacion está bastante completa, raro que no encuentres nada al respecto. Tenes que armar los componentes como vistas, llamarlos en el index del router y definirlos con sus path correspondientes. Te recomiendo que intentes eso y despues vemos como pasar de una vista a la otra

Comment: definidas ya las tengo las vistas, con sus rutas, lo que quiero es cambiar de vista en vez de con vue router, dando click al boton @AgustinG.

Comment: no te entiendo, no podes sencillamente hacer que la funcion que el boton ejecuta haga un ``router.push('/path-de-la-ruta')`` ? (si estas en vue 2 seria ``this.$router.push('/path-de-la-ruta')`` una vez comprobada toda la logica que queres comprobar? pone el codigo de tu componente completo si queres

Comment: Si evitas usar el `vue router`, perderás la gran ventaja que te aporta usar un framework [SPA](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application). Pero si aun así estás dispuesto a eso, ¿por qué simplemente no usas la etiqueta `<a>` de HTML?

Comment: @Desarrollos-Web-Urquiza no uso vue router porque quiero que el componente boton valide ciertos inputs que pondre y una vez validados que me cambie de componente, no se si con vue router puedo validar datos antes de cambiar de vista

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que en algún lugar del template tenés un botón que ejecuta la función

```
<button @click="sendToView(msg,view)"> Hola, soy un boton </button>
```

Entonces en la función sendToView, suponiendo que view es un objeto con la propiedad path de la ruta a la que quiero dirigirme, podrías hacer

> Para Vue 2

```
 methods: {
    sendToView(msg, view) {
     // Comprobas todo lo que sea necesario
     // y finalmente redireccionas
     // ...
      this.$router.push(view.path)
    },
  },
```

> Para vue 3

```
<script>
import router from "@/router";

setup(){
  const sendToView = (msg, view) => {
    router.push(view.path)
  }
  return {
    sendToView
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: me sigue sin funcionar, si que me cambia la url, pero me sigue mostrando la pagina donde estoy, respondo a mi pregunta con los archivos que tengo

Comment: @alteadev y por favor, abrí el inspector de google y decime qué error te marca en consola. Editá la pregunta original agregando lo que puedas. Gracias

Comment: Errores no me salen, y la url cambia correctamente a localhost.../firstlevel pero no me muestra lo que tengo en la vista

Comment: @alteadev y las views las tenes en una carpeta que está dentro de la carpeta components? (pregunto porque siempre views es una carpeta que va a la misma altura que components, no se porque la tenes dentro de esta, pero no creo que sea un problema). Por otro lado, poniendo algo tan simple como "Hola" en el componente HelloApp.vue y "chau" en FirstLevel.vue, aunque cambies de ruta, siempre ves la palabra "Hola"?

Comment: views la tengo dentro de components si, sé que no me está cambiando de vista porque en el template de la vista firstlevel tengo textos distintos a los de la main page

Comment: @alteadev me extraña muchisimo que te pase algo asi y no tengas ni un warning en consola. Bueno, creo que mas que esto no te puedo ayudar, esperemos que un experto lea la pregunta jaja

Comment: si, a ver si alguien que sepa puede dar con el fallo, muchas gracias

Comment: encontre algo, he implementado vue-router pero cuando meto el router view me duplica las vistas

Comment: @alteadev y si no estabas mostrando <router-view> como esperabas ver el cambio de rutas? eso no lo aclaraste en la pregunta jaja. Otra vez, ahora con las rutas duplicadas no tenes un error en consola?

Comment: no porque mi idea era no usar vue router, como te dije lo acabo de implementar, aun asi me duplica vistas, me aparecen todos los componentes que tengo en la misma pagina